# Unity - Detect mouse click on specific element in array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I came from web dev and recently started learning Unity. I am trying to map a 2d array of game objects and detect a mouse click on a specific element, returning its index.

I am struggling to replicate an "array.map" function in unity where I can attack an "on-click" to each element. I'm looking for something like:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Column; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Row; j++)
        {
            void onClickDetected()
            {
                Debug.Log(i + j);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help here would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a bunch of non UI `GameObject` type elements on which you want to have an event available so you could listen for mouse clicks performed on them.

One solution would be to make a separate script with an [event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/event) made using a C# [delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/) which would get triggered by [`OnMouseDown`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html). You would need to attach this script to each one of your clickable elements. Then the script that contains your clickable element array would attach a method to each instance's event.

### Example

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClickableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action<ClickableObject> MouseDown;

    // A collider component is required for OnMouseDown to work
    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        MouseDown?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private ClickableObject[] clickableObjects = new ClickableObject[0];

    private void Start()
    {
        foreach (ClickableObject unit in clickableObjects)
            unit.MouseDown += OnClickableObjectMouseDown;
    }

    private void OnClickableObjectMouseDown(ClickableObject unit)
    {
        Debug.Log($"{unit.name} clicked!");
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        foreach (ClickableObject unit in clickableObjects)
            unit.MouseDown -= OnClickableObjectMouseDown;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I had made the assumption you were using GameObjects with the UI Button component. If you are using GameObjects with colliders instead, use @Quickz's answer.

Welcome to Unity!

There are two ways I would approach handling adding an onClick to an array of buttons. You can either add the onClick in the inspector, then assign the function as well as parameters for the onClick **or** you can add the onClick in code by adding listeners to your buttons.

For your use case by simply printing which button index is pressed, I would find it easier to automate this task in code. Here is how I would handle it.

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class YourClassNameHere : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private List<Button> myButtons = new List<Button>();
    
    private void Start()
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < myButtons.Count; ++x)
        {
            myButtons[x].onClick.AddListener(delegate{ButtonClicked(x);});   
        }
    }
    
    private void ButtonClicked(int idx)
    {
        Debug.log("Button of index: " + idx " was clicked!");   
    }
}
```

If you would prefer to use an array just make sure you have a constant size and swap the `private List<Button> myButtons = new List<Button>()` to `private UnityEngine.UI.Button[] myButtons = new UnityEngine.UI.Button[YOUR_MAX_SIZE_HERE];`. You would also need to change the iterator condition to be YOUR_MAX_SIZE_HERE or use the myButtons.Length instead of Count.

Add this script to a manager, I would pick the parent object of your buttons. Then select all your button objects and drag them into the list or array field in the inspector to popular them. You can also grab all of the references in code by using a `foreach (Transform child in parent)` but when dealing with a static amount of objects in a scene, I would prefer to drag in the references by hand.